# Pulling a list of related objects in a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a list of contacts and each contact can has multiple interactions - these are both tables in a the databases. One contact can have many interactions

So I would load contacts and preload all the interactions. I have found that you can use includes which is great.

Now I am trying to pull a list of distinct interaction names off the list of contacts.

```
@contacts = Contacts.all
```

How can I pull all distinct interactions from this list?

I would have thought something like

```
@interactions = @contacts.interactions
```

or something to that affect

I don't want to load all interactions and work backwards since I am on the contact page.

Comment: I got my example working along these lines. Contact.all.includes(:interaction).map{ |z| z.interaction }

Comment: from your comment it seems like each contact has one interaction, which is not what you said in the question

Comment: What do your interaction records look like? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write in this way

```
Model.include('associated_model_name').select("DISTINCT value").where('condition =?', condition)
```

Or you can do

```
Model.uniq.pluck(:column_name)
```